# Can I change the appearance of the bootloader, ..?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader, burg

I was bored with my bootloader, ..
Can I change the theme of the bootloader, ..
I was looking on google, and I found the burg,.
but I could not use it because my pc is UEFI, ..
I dual boot windows8.1 and ubuntu14.10

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing xubuntu or kubuntu by enter in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install xubuntu
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

and it has two difference of boot loader theme, and those look better, and it works fine whit my pc this way.

Comment: Although that may be easy, installing xubuntu or kubuntu is overkill to say the least.

Comment: @Michael  Installing a whole new plethora of stuff just for an eye-candy GRUB bootloader image is too much of work and ain't worth it, IMHO.

Comment: You could maybe them autoremove them, and the boot loader is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were "bored" as per your question, I am not sure if the below will actually "entertain" you enough or not but if you do not get fooled by the "GRUB2" title in the link am giving, then yeah, you can customize your GRUB Bootloader menu screen to your taste.

http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Splashimages.html

Most of the instructions will work for GRUB as well.  And do not forget to run grub-mkconfig after making the changes :)